# wordpress - links in sub menu for multiple div items

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, wordpress-theming

Ok so I have made a dropdown menu in wordpress. But now I want the links in the sub menu to link to divs on that page. Anyone familiar with this?

Thanks!

PS: This means that the url has to change while still on the same page like so:

**First url**: www.website.com

**Second url**: www.website.com/#div-1(scrolls to div-1)

**Third url**: www.website.com/#div-2(scrolls to div-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use page jumps.
http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/page-jumps/

Comment: It works, but only the first time. When I click on a second link inside the same page, the url doesn't change

Comment: And when I want to go back one page in the browser, I have to back up through all the clicks in a page

Comment: It works! It was the LocalScroll plugin that broke it